# How to use virtualenv and pip in python

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'd like to have a python script which in the beginning create a virtual environment, install required modules (e.g. cherrypy) and then continues with the rest of the code.
What I found so far is as follow:

```
import os, virtualenv

HOME_DIRECTORY = "venv"
virtualenv.create_environment(HOME_DIRECTORY)
execfile(os.path.join(HOME_DIRECTORY, "bin", "activate_this.py"))

import pip
pip.main(["install", "--prefix", HOME_DIRECTORY, "cherrypy"])

import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/')
```

The script creates virtual environment and install cherrypy (based on the log), but still I get `ImportError: No module named cherrypy` error.
I also tried the following, but got the same error:

```
import importlib
CHERRYPY = 'cherrypy'
try:
    importlib.import_module(CHERRYPY)
except ImportError:
    import pip
    pip.main(["install", "--prefix", HOME_DIRECTORY, CHERRYPY])
finally:
    globals()[CHERRYPY] = importlib.import_module(CHERRYPY)
```

Apart from the above problem, also, I'd like to know how to specify the python version (e.g. python 3.6) while creating virtual environment. Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you cd into the new venv and try import the module in the console?

Comment: use python3 -m venv instead of virtualenv

Comment: `conda` is a more powerful tool to manage virtual envs. Have a try.

Comment: wouldn't you be better off running a pip install off of a `requirements.txt` and thus decouple your deps from the code? Also let pip do the heavy lifting and leverage it?

Comment: Your first script doesn't actually seem to install `cherrypy`; what makes you think that it does?

Comment: @jwodder sorry, my bad. I missed some lines. Updated.

Comment: How do you activate/use the new environment you created?

Comment: Shouldn't this do that: `execfile(os.path.join(HOME_DIRECTORY, "bin", "activate_this.py")`?

Comment: @ShawnMehan after executing the above script (and getting the import error), if I open a shell and activate the virtual environment manually (`source venv/bin/activate`) and try to import `cherrypy` I get this error: `ImportError: No module named 'six'`. BTW decoupling is not an option, at least for now.

Comment: Right. Which is a different module and may be a dep for `cherrypy`, I don't know. I haven't used it. But, it further strengthens the arg to use a `requirements.txt` and `pip` to manage the modules in the venv. You should build a venv that does what you want, prove it works, then `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and use that to install into new venvs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record the issue was with the virtual environment activate (the line to execute `activate_this.py`). For Python 3 the following worked for me:

```python
ACTIVATE_THIS = 'venv/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(Path(ACTIVATE_THIS).read_text(), dict(__file__ = ACTIVATE_THIS))
```